# Problem with ros::Timer

Tags: timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I have trouble creating a timer in Ros. I defined a class in which one of its members is the timer callback. To create it, in the constructor of the class I put the following:

```
timer = nh.createTimer(ros::Duration(0.1), &summit_xl_path_planning::PathPlanningSpin, this);
```

("timer" is a `ros::Timer` member of the class)

And then define the callback as below:

```
void summit_xl_path_planning::PathPlanningSpin(const ros::TimerEvent& e)
{
...
}
```

Finally in the main summit_xl_path_planning I create a class, to make things work. I run the node using rosrun.

The problem is that I never get to run the timer. The program compiles. When I run everything I put in the constructor is done, but then nothing else happens. I have reviewed the tutorials thousands of times, but I can not see I'm doing wrong. Can anybody help?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and Fuerte.

Thanks in advance and best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42188/problem-with-ros::timer/) by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2012-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, you didn't give us enough information (e.g. source code) in your question so I can just guess. Here a few things that can go wrong:

- Are you calling `ros::spin()` or `ros::spinOnce()` in a loop somewhere in your program? Spinning will call the timer callbacks.
- Is your `NodeHandle` object maybe stack allocated in the constructor and destroyed at the end of it? The live time of timer objects, publishers and subscribers is bound to the NodeHandle they were created with. Make sure that the NodeHandle is a member variable of the class that starts the timer.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on 2012-08-24**:
Thanks! I was callin ros::spin(), but the NodeHandle was not a member variable of the class. Sorry for this dummy question ;)